# Difference between feature to raster and polygon to raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, rasterization

(I'm using Arc 10.1)

I'm trying to rasterize a data set. I have a shapefile with geographic coordinates (GCS_GDA_1994) which I want to convert to a raster with 100m grid cells. So I need to project into a projected SRS - I used GDA_1994_South_Australia_Lambert but I don't think it matter which one for my question. So I did that, and afterwards I tried to use 'Polygon to raster' to convert to a raster. However, in the input field 'Cellsize' I get by default a very small value (0.0002 or so) - reading the help file, this makes me thing it is because it is still using degrees as the unit there. And indeed when I put in 100 there (for 100 meters), I get one big cell; it is using the wrong unit. When I check 'linear unit' under the layer properties, it does say 'Meter' however.

So then I tried Feature to Raster and lo and behold, I get a default suggestion in the correct order of magnitude and putting in 100 manually gives me a 100m raster.

Now, Polygon to raster has more options that control how the value of the cell is calculated, and I need that. So my question is: what is the difference between these two tools that makes one use a different unit than the other, and how can I make 'Polygon to raster' use meters?

Comment: Arc 9.1 is getting a bit old, but no doubt you're aware of that. For the purposes of this tool the spatial reference is sort-of not necessary... all that matters is cell size. Try removing your spatial reference (prj file) and let it use an assumed projection then put your projection back when you're finished. A non-SRID spatial reference may be a little too much! Also check your environments to see that you're not specifying an output coordinate system or cell size.

Comment: Sorry not sure what I was thinking there - I'm using 10.1, I've corrected my question. What do you mean by 'non-SRID'? Sorry if that's something basic - I'm just learning about GIS. I checked my environments and there is nothing strange there.

Comment: SRID spatial references are the ones you can "pick off the shelf", they have numbers like 28355 is MGA94 Zone 55. Anything else is non-SRID i.e. they are based on parameters and thereby *custom*. Try googling SRID GDA94 and check out the results. When ArcGis chooses a cell size it looks at the projection and tries to match it up, if it's custom it might not get it right, what I'm suggesting is remove the prj file and let it assume projected coordinates and then apply the correct spatial reference when it's done.